# R Generating plots inside for loop don't flow par dimentions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I wrote a for loop to make a matrix of charts, however I wrote the code as following

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 4))

for (i in c(6:17)) {
  print(ggpubr::ggboxplot(logdat, 
                          x = "Diagnostic", 
                          y = names(logdat)[i] , 
                          color = "Diagnostic", 
                          add = "jitter") + 
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons,
                       method = "t.test")) 
}
```

Only individual graphs are shown and not the matrix I want

Comment: Can you supply some data ? Try to make posts reproducible

Comment: Interesting question. Would like to help but cannot. Please set up a [MCVE] including all `library` lines and UDF assignments. Your code should run in empty R environments free from local disk files for us to help. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `ggboxplot` from `ggpubr` which is based on `ggplot2`, which is based on `grid` graphics system. Unfortunately, `grid` graphics does not work with `base` R graphics, so setting `par` doesn't work either. To arrange plots created by the library build on top of `grid` please use the `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` package. See the example below:

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
grobsList <- list()
for (i in c(1:4)) {

  p <- ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8)
  grobsList <- c(grobsList, list(p))
}


gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  grobs = grobsList, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

You can also try to use `marrangeGrob` but it might create the plot outside the current graphical window.

You can also render the plots inside the loop when the desired number of plots were created:

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
grobsList <- list()

for (i in c(1:7)) {

  p <- ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8)
  grobsList <- c(grobsList, list(p))

  if(length(grobsList) == 4) {
    # print the result
    gridExtra::grid.arrange(
      grobs = grobsList, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
    grobsList <- list() # reset the list containing the plots
  }
}

# print the remaining plots
if(length(grobsList) > 0) {
  gridExtra::grid.arrange(
    grobs = grobsList, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight , that was great. However, on my data it gives me error when  I put the nrow argument " Error: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE". also all the graphs are collapsed and not saving the position. any ideas

Comment: Oh, when there's no space on the page in `base` graphics, it automatically creates a new drawing area. However, in `grid` graphics, this is not a case, so the number of plots should be lower than the ncol*nrow. I'll edit the answer to take this into account.

Comment: I don't understand any of your code but this solved my problem. You are a genius thank you